# Updating Applet with random color

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am trying to make a JFrame with a background that changes slowly over time.
here's my code:

```
public class RainbowWindow extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Color color = new Color(((int) Math.random()), ((int) Math.random()), ((int) Math.random()), 255);
        setBackground(color);

    }
}
```

but all i get is just a black screen

Comment: 1. [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free); 2. DON'T create a `Timer` in `paint`, paint is called EVERY TIME the component needs to be painted and often in quick succession; 3. `JFrame` != `Applet`

Comment: 4. `Math.random` returns a value between 0 and 1, `Color` expects a values between 0-255

Comment: I changed 'Color color = new Color(((int) Math.random()), ((int) Math.random()), ((int) Math.random()), 255);' to 'Color color = new Color(((int) Math.random() * 256), ((int) Math.random() * 256), ((int) Math.random() * 256), 255);'

Comment: `(int)Math.random() * 255` is going to convert the result from `Math.random()` to an `int` by truncating the floating point values (`0.1` becomes `0`), you want `(int)(Math.random() * 255)` - remember, it's `0-255` not `0-256`

Answer (score 2):

1. [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)
2. DON'T create a `Timer` in `paint`, paint is called EVERY TIME the component needs to be painted and often in quick succession. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) nd [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing
3. You sould avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame` and `Applet`, they aren't double buffered and it tends to cause no end of issues, better to start with some kind of component and add it to whatever container you want
4. `JFrame` != `Applet`
5. `Math.random` returns a value between `0` and `1`, `Color` expects a values between `0`-`255`

For example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int red = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
                    int green = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
                    int blue = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
                    Color color = new Color(red, green, blue, 255);
                    setBackground(color);
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be extending `JApplet` (not `Applet`), and adding a component to set the color on, and you shouldn't be starting a `Timer` in your `paint` method, and you casting a floating point value to an `int` isn't going to give you any values in your random color generation. Something like,

```
public class RainbowWindow extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Color color = new Color(((int) (Math.random() * 255)),
                ((int) (Math.random() * 255)),
                ((int) (Math.random() * 255)), 255);
        panel.setBackground(color);
    }

    public RainbowWindow() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Which I tested, and it changes the background color to a new random color once a second.

Comment: Applets are finally officially, dead: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). Although the OP is using a `Applet` in their example code, they did say `JFrame` ... so, that's not confusing :P